# Character classes using byte regex for characters encoded with multiple bit blocks

Tags: python, regex, unicode, encoding, byte

I would like to use regular expressions on bytestrings in python of which I know the encoding (utf-8). I am facing difficulties trying to use character classes that involve characters that are encoded using more than one bit block. They appear to become two or more 'characters' that are matched separately in the character class.

Performing the search on (unicode) strings instead is possible, but I would like to know if there is a solution to defining character classes for the case of bytestrings as well. Maybe it's just not possible!?

Below is a python 3 example that shows what happens when I try to replace different line breaks with `'\n'`:

```py
import re

def show_pattern(pattern):
    print(f"\nPattern repr:\t{repr(pattern)}")

def test_sub(pattern, replacement, text):
    print(f"Before repr:\t{repr(text)}")
    result = re.sub(pattern, replacement, text)
    print(f"After repr:\t{repr(result)}")

# Pattern for line breaks
PATTERN = '[' + "\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029" + ']'
REPLACEMENT = '\n'
TEXT = "How should I replace my unicode string\u2028using utf-8-encoded bytes?"

show_pattern(PATTERN)
test_sub(PATTERN, REPLACEMENT, TEXT)
# expected output:
# Pattern repr: '[\n\x0b\x0c\r\x85\u2028\u2029]'
# Before repr:  'How should I replace my unicode string\u2028using utf-8-encoded bytes?'
# After repr:   'How should I replace my unicode string\nusing utf-8-encoded bytes?'

ENCODED_PATTERN = PATTERN.encode('utf-8')
ENCODED_REPLACEMENT = REPLACEMENT.encode('utf-8')
ENCODED_TEXT = TEXT.encode('utf-8')

show_pattern(ENCODED_PATTERN)
test_sub(ENCODED_PATTERN, ENCODED_REPLACEMENT, ENCODED_TEXT)
# expected output:
# Pattern repr: b'[\n\x0b\x0c\r\xc2\x85\xe2\x80\xa8\xe2\x80\xa9]'
# Before repr:  b'How should I replace my unicode string\xe2\x80\xa8using utf-8-encoded bytes?'
# After repr:   b'How should I replace my unicode string\n\n\nusing utf-8-encoded bytes?'
```

In the encoded version, I end up with three `'\n'`'s instead of one. Similar things happen for a more complicated document where it's not obvious what the correct output should be.

Comment: Try using `PATTERN = "|".join(['\u000A','\u000B','\u000C','\u000D','\u0085','\u2028','\u2029'])`

Comment: Yes that works, thanks. For more generality we could do ```CHARACTERS = "\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029"
PATTERN = "|".join([char for char in CHARACTERS]'```.
That is basically mimicking the character class definition. So I guess there is no way to make the expression understand which bit blocks belong together...? If you formulate your comment as an answer I can select it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use an alternation based pattern rather than a character class, as you will want to match *sequences* of bytes:

```
PATTERN = "|".join(['\u000A','\u000B','\u000C','\u000D','\u0085','\u2028','\u2029'])
```

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/DJN84441).

If you prefer to initialize the pattern from a string use

```
CHARS = "\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029"
PATTERN = "|".join(CHARS)
```

Comment: Or `PATTERN = "|".join(CHARS)`, since strings are iterable.